# How can I avoid ListView flashing the view set by @android:id/empty before loading data.

Tags: android, listview

I am loading data from a sqlite db to populate for the listview. however when the app runs, it shows the view associated with the empty view (@android:id/empty) and then it gets replaced by the data in the list view. Is there a way avoid that.

```
    <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:divider="@drawable/top_drop_shadow"
    android:dividerHeight="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableBottom="@drawable/read_book"
    android:text="Nothing to read here, go read a book instead"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this behavior, provide the empty View only when you have loaded the data and updated your Adapter.

Comment: thanks, however if you see i am using default ids, so i don't use an explicit assignment of the empty view to the list. would that mean i would need to define custom ids and manually assign in code?

Comment: Yes you could do this. Or you could create a custom Adapter, and override the `isEmpty()` method. Returning `false` as long as you don't have updated the data, and returning `super.isEmpty()` after

Comment: i refactored the code but still get the error. 
`  View emptyLv = rootView.findViewById(R.id.feedlist_empty);
  FeedListAdapter feedListAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(getActivity()
    .getApplicationContext(), R.layout.feed_item, items);
  lv.setAdapter(feedListAdapter);
  lv.setEmptyView(emptyLv);
`

including trying to reset the empty view everytime the fragment is destroyed
` @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  lv.setEmptyView(null);
 }
`

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Simon's answer with a code example, overriding my `CursorAdapter`'s `isEmpty()` worked perfectly for me:

```
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (getCursor() == null) {
        return false; // Data not yet loaded, so don't show empty view
    }
    else {
        return super.isEmpty(); // Data loaded, so show empty view if required
    }
}
```

With this solution, I didn't need to change my layout file, but here it is for completeness:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView 
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="No data"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

NB - In my Java code, I have no calls to `getListView().setEmptyView()` or anything like that, so all my layout code stays in the layout file. :)